# sql count statement leads to wrong value

Tags: sql

```
select count(d.Games_played),count(d.No_ofgames) from 
(
 SELECT COUNT(UserGamePlayed.intID) AS 'Games_played',games.vchCompetency,b.No_Games as 'No_ofgames'
 FROM UserGamePlayed
 inner join games on games.intGameID=UserGamePlayed.intGameID
 inner join 
 (
 select COUNT(Games.intGameID) AS 'No_Games',vchCompetency,intGradeID from Games
 WHERE intGradeID=3
 GROUP BY vchCompetency,intGradeID
 ) as b on b.vchCompetency=games.vchCompetency
 WHERE intUserID=403 and UserGamePlayed.intGradeID=3
 GROUP BY games.vchCompetency,b.No_Games
)as d
```

the table which i get from d is:[image]

As per the table d i want to get a count of played,when exicute a full i am getting
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `COUNT` with `SUM` (in your outer select only).

`COUNT` only counts (as the name indicates ;)) the rows while `SUM` will add up the values that are passed to it.